# What would you call something that you learned?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I need a word for an incident that you've read, I don't really know how else to describe it. But here's the context...

> I connected this book to the world when I learned that this character had been raped at the summer break party. I connected this ________ to the world because I've heard about the rapes that happen around the world, especially in colleges where women are raped, and don't speak up about it because they are afraid that it will hurt others or that they will be looked at different.

Comment: Information; facts provided or learned about something or someone. Or depends on how you consider what you read. http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/information

Comment: Hi Kelley, no need to introduce yourself, your name is added automatically.

Comment: I would say "reality" Or "unfortunate event"

Answer (score 2):

I would go with **disclosure** or possibly **revelation**. Here, the point is not so much the you learned it, as it is that the character chose to disclose or reveal it.

Answer (score 0):

> I connected this ***scene/episode*** to the world because...

Macmillan Dictionary:

> **[scene](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/scene#scene__1)**
> *NOUN [COUNTABLE]*
>
> **1** a **part of a** play, **book**, movie, etc. in which events happen in the same place or period of time
>
> a love scene; opening/final scene: the opening scene of Macbeth
>
> **[episode](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/episode)**
> *NOUN [COUNTABLE]*
>
> **1** an event or set of events that forms part of a longer series but is considered separately
>
> The raid was one of the bloodiest episodes in
> a long hard war.
>
> After this episode, relations between them were
> strained.

Answer (score 0):

I connected this *matter* to the world...

> *MATTER NOUN* A subject or situation under consideration. [- ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/matter#matter__7)

This might be a nice fit, since you connect the fictionalized event by thinking about it. As such it is a situation under consideration.